# Why is variable declared in an if-statement still in scope in else block?

Tags: c++, if-statement, language-lawyer, variable-declaration

Consider this code:

```
if (int* p = nullptr) {
}
else {
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles with clang 7.0.1 with `-std=c++17`, `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-pedantic-errors` without a single warning generated.

I've got two questions:

1. How is this possible? I always thought that scope of such variables ends with the if-block. I'd be thankful for quotation from the standard if possible.
2. If it's legal though, shouldn't it at least generate a warning? Are there any reasonable applications of such feature?

Comment: "*I always thought that scope of such variables ends with the if-block.*" The else ***is*** part of the if-block.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the opening bracket comes after the initialization

Comment: [cppreference's description of if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) mentions that "The scope of the name introduced by _condition_, if it is a declaration, is the combined scope of both statements' bodies"

Comment: It seems totally reasonable to me.  As in your example, if the condition is the truthiness of some complicated expression, this gives you a way to declare a variable to hold the value of that expression, and you might want to know in either of the two clauses what that value was.

Comment: Actually, one almost wishes you could declare variables for subexpressions, and do `if ((int c = getchar()) == EOF) { close_file(); } else { process_character(c); }`

Comment: @NateEldredge • you can `if (int c = getchar(); c == EOF) ...`

Comment: @Eljay true, but only in C++17 and later.

Comment: @NicolBolas "The else is part of the if-block. " Well I would say it's part of the if-**statement**, not the if-**block** . Wouldn't that be more precise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is variable declared in an if-statement still in scope in else block?

Because the standard says that it is. It was designed so presumably because it is useful.

> 1. How is this possible?

It's unclear why it wouldn't be possible.

> I always thought that scope of such variables ends with the if-block.

You assumed wrongly.

> I'd be thankful for quotation from the standard if possible. [language-lawyer]

Latest draft says:

> [stmt.select.general]
>
> Selection statements choose one of several flows of control.
> selection-statement:
>
> - ...
> - if constexpr<sub>opt</sub> ( init-statement<sub>opt</sub> condition ) statement else statement
> - ...

Note that the entire `if (condition) statement else statement` is a selection-statement.

> [basic.scope.block]
>
> Each
>
> - selection or iteration statement ([stmt.select], [stmt.iter]),
> - ...
>
> introduces a block scope that includes that statement or handler.

Note that the *condition* is directly within the if-statement and not inside a sub-statement, and thus a declaration within it extends until the end of the entire block scope, which contains both the if-sub-statement, and the else-sub-statement (not standard names for those sub-statements).

There is also a pretty clear example that demonstrates ill-formed re-declarations, and incidentally shows the scope of such declaration:

> ```
> if (int x = f()) {
>   int x;            // error: redeclaration of x
> }
> else {
>   int x;            // error: redeclaration of x
> }
> ```

---

> 2. If it's legal though, shouldn't it at least generate a warning?

Yeah, it would be nice if compilers were able to detect all provable null pointer indirections at compile time. It may be worth submitting a feature request regarding this corner case.

> Are there any reasonable applications of such feature?

Sure. Following fabricated example seems reasonable to me:

```
if (Response r = do_request()) {
    log << "great success. content: " << r.content;
} else {
    log << "someone broke it :( error: " << r.error_code;
}
```

Or if you dislike implicit conversions:

```
if (Response r = do_request(); r.is_success()) {
```

Comment: The best explanation I've seen is that `if (x) {y();} else {z();}` is _actually_ `{bool x_cond = x; if (x_cond) {y();} else {z();}}`, which explains the scope.

Comment: @MooingDuck There's a scenario where this analogy breaks: `if (int x = 1) {int x = 2;}`. This gives me `error: redefinition of 'x'`.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because it covers all points I've mentioned, one nitpick though: 
"Yeah, it would be nice if compilers were able to detect all provable null pointer indirections at compile time." Of course that would be nice, but that was not my point - I just thought (and still think, despite the examples provided) that referencing the variable in further else blocks hinders code clarity (i. e. is seldom desirable) and *that* fact should be flagged with a warning. It's just my opinion though.

Comment: @mdx Flagging the use of a variable within the scope where it is declared would be counter productive since that's typically the only place where the variable can be referenced in.

Comment: @eerorika I see the point you're making, but I wouldn't say so. I for one find this feature more dangerous than productive. One example of it being undesirable is copying an else-if branch of a longer if-ladder and forgetting to change the variable name inside of it. Flagging such situations as warnings would be a useful thing to have at a pretty low price IMO.